# Virtualbox remote access on ubuntu server

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, putty, ubuntu-server, x11-forwarding

I explain the problem, I have to connect via ssh tunneling enabling x11, to a remote machine with ubuntu server, in detail:

- Host: Windows 7, the software used putty
- Server: ubuntu server virtualbox installed in the machine

I would only remotely access a virtualbox, because of port forwarding I can not expose virtualbox as a service

If you need more just ask

thank you very much